# Visitors still seeing old web page…why?

Tags: browser

I updated my page content (HTML), and uploaded to the server. But when I browse the page using Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox. It shows me the content before I update.

What if the users browse my site and see the old content without hit the refresh?

Is it my hosting problem?

Comment: You either uploaded it to the wrong place or the page is cached.

Comment: without hitting refresh user see the old page.. didnt get your this line.

Comment: Most chances are that your server caches the content. Try to restart it and see if it is still the case.

Comment: I upload it to the right place. I can see the new content after I refresh my page. But other user don't know my page is new content unless they refresh the page. Is it my hosting problem?

Comment: You are not using interactive method to send data to users, so they must refresh the page, unless they can only view what they had in their own browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clean your history in your browser.

In *Firefox*,

> 1. Go to Firefox > History > Clear recent history or (if no Firefox button is shown) go to Tools > Clear recent history.
> 2. Under "Time range to clear", select "Everything".
> 3. Now, click the arrow next to Details to toggle the Details list active.
> 4. From the details list, check Cache and Cookies and uncheck everything else.
> 5. Now click the Clear now button.

In *Chrome*,

> 1. Go to Settings on the top-right corner of the browser
> 2. History button on the left
> 3. Check the cached images and files
> 4. Clear browsing data

Also, having a look at your site in other browser which you've never visited in before is also a good choice.

Sometimes you need to wait until the server finished making new cache. I'd had this experience once, just *need some time*. If you still got your problem, try to contact the server provider, who usually has a online support chat room.

Some references by Chrome and Mozilla communities:

- Chrome https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/xR-6YAkcASQ
- Mozilla Firefox https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/967500

Comment: If I want to get the new cache now from server? Is it possible?

Comment: Users still need to hit *refresh button*, unless they can only see the old site. Once the browser refreshed, it will ask the server to send data and see if there's any change since last loading. If there is any change, they'll get the new one. So, if the server didn't make new, the browser still get the old files, which is stored in their own computer.

Comment: Have you tested in any other computer so far?

Comment: Yes. I updated my HTML files. My client told me she can't see the changes. I have to ask her to refresh her browser. I feel like not so professional. :(

I also test it in my office pc (windows). Same. Have to refresh.

Comment: Don't worry, sometimes it happens beyond our expects. So now did she do refresh? If she did refresh and couldn't see anything changed, that would be another problem you should notice.

Comment: She can see the changes after refresh. Thanks bro!!

Comment: So nice to see that! :D

Answer (score 3):

If it is a cache problem then just press `clrt+R`. This is the command for hard refresh. Hope if this occurred by the cache problem then it will be solved. But check whether the you have updated the right file or not

Comment: But users don't know my webpage have new content, unless they refresh the page every time they visit my webpage.

Answer (score 1):

This may help in your future deploy.

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

Answer (score 0):

If on windows go clear the temp files

Go to run and type in 
Temp
%temp%

Deleting everything in these folders generally fix the problem